# Boost Python Memory Leak

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

I have a code that does some calculations in c++ and then returns the results to python using boost.python (and boost.numpy). To be more precise there is a simplified example. First of all its a function

```
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;

std::pair<np::ndarray, np::ndarray> f() {
    const auto dt = np::dtype::get_builtin<double>();
    np::ndarray a = np::empty(a_shape, dt);
    np::ndarray b = np::empty(b_shape, dt);
    // filling arrays
    return {std::move(a), std::move(b)};
}
```

which returns a pair of numpy arrays. Also there is a class which I export to python:

```
namespace p = boost::python;

class WrappedClass {
public:
    p::dict GetData() {
        p::dict result;
        for (const std::string& key : keys_) {
            auto arrays = f();
            result[key] = p::make_tuple(std::move(arrays.first), std::move(arrays.second));
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Everything works fine: I call `GetData()` method from python and get a correct data. The problem is all these numpy arrays (and probably dicts as well) I create are never deleted even if all references to them in the python code are (and calling `gc.collect()` doesn't help at all). The destructor of the `WrappedClass` instance is called when I do `del` of this instance in python.

What is the right way to return python objects from a c++ code to avoid memory leaks?